# option select onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a primitive question, but I am new to JS/jQuery.

I have several different select boxes on a page. Each of them has an image next to, that is changed, when a different option is selected. However, this only works fine for one select box with getElementById, but it doesn't work with getElementByClassName for many of them, nor do I want to use this method, since I read it's not supported by IE8.0. Is there a way to make this work for multiple select boxes within one page, without using separate IDs for each one of them?

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code.

```
<img id="color" src="content/1.png"> 
<select class="mod_select" name="colors" id="changingColor" tabindex="1" onchange="changeimg()">
<option value="content/1.png">1 thing</option>
<option value="content/2.png">2 thing</option>
<option value="content/3.png">3 thing</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeimg(){
document.getElementById('color').src=document.getElementById('changingColor').value
}
</script>
```

Edit: I'd like to use classes both for select and for img. Then within one div have a particular select option change the img next to it. Is that possible?

Edit 2: This works great:

```
$('.mod_select').on('change', function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     var img = $this.prev(); // assuming select is next to img
     img.attr('src', $this.val());
 });
```

However, the img is not next to select, I think I should use prevSibling, but I'm not sure how. Reading jQuery API didn't help me much. 
I would really appreciate your help! Here's my html:

```
 <img src="content/1.png"> <!-- the image that needs to be updated with new select option -->
 <p>text</p>
 <div class="moreinfo info_icon left"></div> <!-- the div that triggers qTip -->
 <div class="moreinfo_text"> <!-- this is a hidden div this that is shown by qTip with -- text: $(this).next('.moreinfo_text') -->
      <img src="content/qtip_img.jpg">
      <p>qTip text</p> 
 </div> 
 <select class="mod_select" name="colors" tabindex="1">
      <option value="content/1.png">1 thing</option>
      <option value="content/2.png">2 thing</option>
      <option value="content/3.png">3 thing</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: The `id` attribute on elements should be unique, so they should have separate IDs anyway. If you want to group multiple elements together then you should use a class.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you please:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   $('.mod_select').change(function() {
    $('.mod_select option:selected').each(function() {
     $('#color').attr('src', $(this).val());
    });
   });

});
```

You should add something like

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
!window.jQuery && document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"><\/script>')
/* ]]> */</script>
```

to the  to add jQuery.

Comment: Note:  You'll have to remove all your other javascript, and be sure to add jQuery to the page.

Comment: Dear user1477388, it does work, however with the script you provided I should assign different IDs to each img. I would prefer to have a dynamic content on my page, so I'd like to use classes both for select and for img. Then within one div a particular select option changes the img next to it. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you can.  Just change `#color` to class `.color` and put your `.mod_select` and `.color` elements inside a div element assigned with its own class name, too.  You would access them like `$('.myDivClassNames .mod_select')`.  Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery provides a very powerful selector, you can use a class selector to achieve your goal like the following:

1. Remove `onchange` attribute from select.
2. Edit your javascript.

   ```
   $('.mod_select').on('change', function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       var img = $this.prev(); // assuming select is next to img
       img.attr('src', $this.val());
   });
   ```

Comment: This works great, however I can't figure out how to trigger the img if it's not next to select. I updated my question, would be grateful if you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: @IrinaDihtjara Are you able to add a class to the image you want updated or not? If you are able to add a class then the method I show in my example will work even with your updated html. I will include a jQuery example of the same code if you want to use jQuery instead.

Comment: In that case, I think you'd better wrap img and corresponding select in a div. Then, find img by jQuery's Filter method:

`var img = $this.parent().find('img:first-child');`

Answer (score 1):

Since IE 8 doesn't support `getElementsByClassName` you can create your own version of it using the `getElementsByTagName` that Internet Explorer does support. Once you have the array of elements you can iterate over them and assign an event handler for the `change` event instead of having to do it inline with the html. Once this is done, all you need to do is find the image element by its class name using `previousSibling` or `nextSibling` and change its source.

**Here is the javascript**

```
var select = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'mod_select');
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
    select[i].onchange = function() {
      var prevSibling = this.previousSibling;
      while(prevSibling && prevSibling.className != 'image') {
           prevSibling = prevSibling.previousSibling;
      }
      prevSibling.src = this.value;
    }
}

function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
```

Here is a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsuzP/2/) showing this. Note: this does not require any jQuery :)

**edit**

jQuery does all of the heavy lifting for you and you can change the above code to simply

```
$('.mod_select').change(function(){
    $(this).prevAll('img:first').attr('src', this.value); 
});
```

This looks among all the previous sibling elements for the first image it comes to and changes its source. You can change the selector to include the class name you mentioned you wanted to add in your first edit. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsuzP/3/) showing the code with jQuery.